# Can't use Accord.NET

Tags: c#, accord.net

I have Installed Accord.Net. But when I add "Accord.Math" as a reference then it shows  "The referenced component 'Accord.Math' could not be found."
I don't know why. Any one help me why showing this and how i solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions in [Getting Started](https://code.google.com/p/accord/wiki/GettingStarted) for **adding references**? You have to have the DLLs present in your project in order to be able to use them.

Comment: The problem is solved. I installed Accord.NET 2.8.1 which is for .NET version 4. But I am using .NET3.5 . There is another version of Accord.NET for .NET3.5