# What is Accord.NET version for .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net-3.5, accord.net

I am using .NET 3.5. I need to use Accord.Math. I installed Accord.NET 2.7.1, 2.8.1, 2.11 and 2.15. But non of them worked. The error message is: The type or namespace name 'Accord' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there anyone to know what version of Accord.Math work with .NET3.5?

Comment: I think you need to find and install the appropriate version. Also, after installing, add the reference of the dll in your project. Similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084482/cant-use-accord-net

Comment: If you are using NuGet, the appropriate version for .NET 3.5 should install automatically. If you are downloading the packages, please be sure to use the .NET 3.5 version of the assemblies that are located in the Release/net35 folder in the installation directory